# Using Type.GetType(string) in IList<T>

Tags: c#, ilist, gettype

Since I can't make any comments (only post an answer) to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/914578/using-type-returned-by-type-gettype-in-c), I'll post a new question.
I followed the instructions from mentioned post, but the code produces an error.
The code:

```
Type t = Type.GetType(className);
Type listType = typeof(List<>).MakeGenericType(t);
IList list = (IList)Activator.CreateInstance(listType);
```

The error:

> Using the generic type 'System.Collections.Generic.IList' requires '1' type arguments

Clearly I can't just state `IList` without any type, so I'm wondering how exactly does the answer from the mentioned post works.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should be able to edit your other question?

Comment: It was not my question, but I have the exact same problem. :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can, you just need a different using directive:

```
using System.Collections;
```

That way you'll be using the nongeneric [`IList`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.ilist.aspx) instead of the generic [`IList<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5y536ey6.aspx).

I believe that's the spirit of the referenced answer.

Comment: Superman could take lessons from you on how to be everywhere he's needed in the blink of an eye. :-p

Answer (score 1):

```
Type t = Type.GetType(className);
Type listType = typeof(List<>).MakeGenericType(t);
IList list = (IList)Activator.CreateInstance(listType);
```

Should do the trick.

You'll have to cast the objects when retrieving them using the IList interface, but the underlying List will enforce that only objects of type T are added to the collection.

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to [create a generic IList through reflection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2198989/creating-a-generic-ilist-instance-using-reflection)?

Comment: Yes. I skipped that post somehow. I searched a lot before posting a question. Anyway, the code I posted works like a charm, I just needed right using directive, like Jon posted. Thanks for the link.